# How do i populate a table from other multiple tables with autoincrement of range and random names

Tags: mysql, database, stored-procedures

I'm having some trouble with my stored procedure.

I'm trying to write a "create script" with a "stored procedure" that takes an input "n" in the interval of 0-100000.

After user input i want all the information to go into a new Table called "T".

```
SELECT * FROM T;
```

I want it to print:

```
+----+------------+----------+---------------+---+----+-----+
| Id | First Namne| Last Name| Street Address| No| Zip| City|
+----+------------+----------+---------------+---+----+-----+
```

The street number should be in the range of 1-300.

Zip should be 5 numbers and can't start with 0.

Every row must be unique even if i remove the ID column.

```
I've made 3 files:
1. Contains 500 unique First Names
2. Contains 500 unique Last Names
3. Contains 335 unique Adresses
```

My take was to make the new table "t" to take in a random first name and a random last name. It would take in 1 adress 300 times and make the adress no go up 300 times then continue to the next adress, that way all my rows would be unique.`enter code here`

This is how far i came before my brain crashed:

```
/*
*   Sets database to users
*/
USE users;


/*
*   Removes tables if exists
*/
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS t;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS first_names;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS last_names;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS street_names;


/*
*   Creating new tables
*/
-- Create table t
CREATE TABLE t(
        player_id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
        first_name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
        last_name VARCHAR (20) NOT NULL,
        street_name VARCHAR (30) NOT NULL,
        street_number SMALLINT(3) NOT NULL,
        zip MEDIUMINT(5) NOT NULL,
        city VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
    );


-- Create table first_names
CREATE TABLE first_names (
    first_name_id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    first_name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
);

Source C:\Database\Inlamning\first_names.txt


-- Create table last_names
CREATE TABLE last_names (
    last_name_id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    last_name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
);

Source C:\Database\Inlamning\last_names.txt


-- Create table street_names
CREATE TABLE street_names (
    street_name_id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    street_name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
);

Source C:\Database\Inlamning\street_names.txt


/*
*   Create PRECEDURE "generate_adress"
*/
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS generate_adress;

DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE generate_adress(x INT, fn VARCHAR(20), ln VARCHAR(20), sn VARCHAR (30), snno SMALLINT(3), zi MEDIUMINT(5), ci VARCHAR(20))

    BEGIN
    SELECT (SELECT CONCAT("generate_adress", NOW())) as "Start";

    IF (x > 100000) THEN
    SELECT ("Max allowed adresser are 100000, value set to 100000") AS "Number of address:";
    SET x = 100000;
    END IF;

    INSERT INTO "t" (first_name, last_name, street_name, street_number, zip, city)

    END$$

DELIMITER ;



CALL generate_adress(1000);

SELECT * FROM t;
```

Help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with this solution! Thank you for the help I recieved!

```
/*************************************************
*
*   Andreas Ekman Newton Java 2
*
*   CREATE  -- Source C:\Database\Test\CREATE.txt
*   File:   -- Source C:\Database\Inlamning\first_names.txt - 358 Unique ID
*   File:   -- Source C:\Database\Inlamning\last_names.txt - 359 Unique ID
*   File:   -- Source C:\Database\Inlamning\street_names.txt - 335 Unique ID
*   File:   -- Source C:\Database\Inlamning\street_numbers.txt - 300 Uniqe ID
*   File:   -- Source C:\Database\Inlamning\zips.txt - 7 Uniqe ID
*   File:   -- Source C:\Database\Inlamning\cities.txt - 7 Uniqe ID
*
**************************************************/
/*
*   Setting database to "Gamers"
*/
USE Gamers;

/*
*   Creating new tables
*/
-- Create table t
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS t;
CREATE TABLE t(
    player_id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    first_name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    last_name VARCHAR (20) NOT NULL,
    street_name VARCHAR (30) NOT NULL,
    street_number SMALLINT(3) NOT NULL,
    zip MEDIUMINT(5) NOT NULL,
    city VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
    );


-- Create table first_names
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS first_names;
CREATE TABLE first_names (
    first_name_id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    first_name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
    );

Source C:\Database\Inlamning\first_names.txt


-- Create table last_names
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS last_names;
CREATE TABLE last_names (
    last_name_id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    last_name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
    );

Source C:\Database\Inlamning\last_names.txt


-- Create table street_names
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS street_names;
CREATE TABLE street_names (
    street_name_id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    street_name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
    );

Source C:\Database\Inlamning\street_names.txt


-- Create table street_numbers
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS street_numbers;
CREATE TABLE street_numbers (
    street_number_id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    street_number SMALLINT(30) NOT NULL
    );

Source C:\Database\Inlamning\street_numbers.txt


-- Create table zip
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS zips;
CREATE TABLE zips (
    zip_id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    zip MEDIUMINT(5) NOT NULL
    );

Source C:\Database\Inlamning\zips.txt


-- Create table citites
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS cities;
CREATE TABLE cities (
    city_id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    city VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
    );

Source C:\Database\Inlamning\cities.txt


/*
*   Create PRECEDURE "generate_adress"
*/
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS generate_adress;

DELIMITER $$

-- CREATE PROCEDURE generate_adress(x INT)
CREATE PROCEDURE generate_adress(x INT)
    BEGIN
        -- Declaring variables
        DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 1;
        DECLARE j INT DEFAULT 1;
        DECLARE k INT DEFAULT 1;
        DECLARE fname VARCHAR(20) DEFAULT 'error';
        DECLARE lname VARCHAR(20) DEFAULT 'error';
        DECLARE stname VARCHAR(30) DEFAULT 'error';
        DECLARE stno SMALLINT(3) DEFAULT '0';
        DECLARE zi MEDIUMINT(5) DEFAULT '0';
        DECLARE ci VARCHAR(20) DEFAULT 'error';

        -- Visualizing the start of generator
        SELECT (SELECT CONCAT("generate_adress", NOW())) as "Start generator!";

        -- Check call ID, max allowed input is 100000
        IF (x > 100000) THEN
            SELECT ("Max allowed addresses are 100000, value set to 100000") AS "Number of adresses";
            SET x = 100000;
        END IF;

        -- Loop for creating inserts to table "t"
        WHILE (i <=x) DO
            -- Setting random value for numbers in the 100's range
            SET @random = FLOOR((RAND()*300 +1));
            -- Setting random value for numbers in the up to 7's range
            SET @randomci = FLOOR((RAND()*7 +1));

            -- Getting random name from first_names table
            SET fname = (SELECT first_name FROM first_names WHERE first_name_id = @random); -- SELECT (fname) as 'first_name';

            -- Getting random last name from last_names table
            SET lname = (SELECT last_name FROM last_names WHERE last_name_id = @random);

            -- Getting street name by ID = k
            SET stname = (SELECT street_name FROM street_names WHERE street_name_id = k);

            -- Getting street name by ID = j
            SET stno = (SELECT street_number FROM street_numbers WHERE street_number_id = j);

            -- Getting a random area code from zips table
            SET zi = (SELECT zip FROM zips WHERE zip_id = @randomci);

            -- Getting a random city from cities table
            SET ci = (SELECT city FROM cities WHERE city_id = @randomci);

            -- Insert data to table called "t"
            INSERT INTO t (first_name, last_name, street_name, street_number, zip, city) VALUES(fname, lname, stname, stno, zi, ci);

            -- Setting the "call generate_adress" counter to tick
            SET i = i+1;

            -- Setting street_name and street_number tick
            SET j = j+1;

            -- Variable counter
            IF (j > 300) THEN
                SET j = 1;
                SET k = k+1;
            END IF;

        -- End of while loop        
        END WHILE;

    -- Visualizing the start of generator
    SELECT (SELECT CONCAT("generate_adress", NOW())) as "Stop generator!";

    -- End of create procedure
    END$$

-- Setting default Delimiter to ;
DELIMITER ;

-- Call command, innout "x" for creating number of x's adresses
CALL generate_adress(1000);

-- View all created addresses
SELECT * FROM t;
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the following high level pseudo-code, you can then code it as in line sql or SP with cursors, and/or use temp tables or save code by using subqueries, etc.:

1- cross join first and last names, this will give you the 250000 rows of all possible unique names

2- cross join street names with a table containing numbers from 1 to 300, this will give you the 100500 rows of unique addresses

3- Select n rows from the first cross join ordered by RAND() (temp table T1)

4- Select n rows from the second cross join ordered by RAND() (temp table T2)

5- Join T1 and T2 on row number and that will be your result of n unique rows

The ZIP codes can be worked out as 100000 * RAND()

**EDIT**

pseudocode a bit more elaborated:

```
set @rownum=0
create table t1 as
(
select @rownum:=@rownum+1 as rownum, x.* 
from (select firstname, lastname from firstnames, lastnames) as x limit 10
) x1

set @rownum=0
create table t2 as
(
select @rownum:=@rownum+1 as rownum, x.* 
from (select number, streetname from streetnames, numbers) as x limit 10
) x1

select * from t1 join t2 on t1.rownum=t2.rownum
```

Comment: Hmm, this doesnt' really seem that effective. I don't really need unique names first of all. I just want to call my method like "CALL generate(5)" and it generates 5 rows of data. And if I remove the ID of the column the data should still be unique and that is achieved by the street and streenumber cross join.

Also I don't want to cross join 100500 streets and names everytime the create script is executed so i need a solution for where the table updates the N value i put in in the CALL(N).

I'm really new so having a hard time translating the pseudocode, can't find any related problems

Comment: you don't need to cross the 100500 address with the 250000, you just need to pick N rows from each table and then join on row number or just pick one of each on a while loop of N iterations.  The cross join of names (500x500) and addresses (335x300) should be quick.

Comment: They takes some time but that might be how it's supposed to be.How would I write the while loop for this?

Comment: But why cross join whole tables? How do i  CROSS JOIN N times so I don't have to CROSS JOIN 100500 times when i only need 10 rows?

Comment: Please see the edit, I used limit 10, but that could also be a variable coming from the caller to determine the desired number of rows